# is there a way to make aws lambda function return 404

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function that searches in a dictionary if a particular ID exists. If so returns it with code 200 to APIGATEAWAY but if the ID is not found, I want her to return to API code 404.
That means the HTTPStatus will be 404..
Is there a way to do that?
Right now this is what I tried:

```
def GET(event):
    tab = table.scan()['Items']
    if event.get("wmId") != None:
        try:
            id= [item for item in tab if item["id"]  == event["id"]]
            return id[0]
    except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

Answer (score 3):

You can can either switch to using Lambda proxy integration, in which case you would return a dict that includes the status code, or you will need to return an error string and map that to an appropriate response in the API Gateway integration and method responses. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html